# How to know address belongs to current Ledger, way to get path ? (By using Ledger inside browser - JavaScript)

Tags: public-key, ledger-nano-s

Ledger can generate many wallet addresses,

Is there way how to find out that given **public key address** belongs to currently **connected Ledger** device ? (Using JavaScript API in web application)

And closely coupled question is also if there is way to get ledger path of given address eg. `m/44'/60'/0'/166`?